# Can't create silverlight object via Silverlight.js

Tags: javascript, silverlight

Silverlight doesn't work in Firefox and Chrome (only IE) when I create silverlight object via silverlight.js

```
Silverlight.createObject(
    source,
    document.getElementById("SLContainer"),
    "SLObj",
    {   
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
        onError: "Viewer_HandleError",
        background: 'white',
        minRuntimeVersion: '4.0.60129.0'
    },
    {},
    "fooName=fooVal");
```

I notice, that in generated HTML code attributes of SL object are: `type="application/x-silverlight"` and `data="data:application/x-silverlight,"`. 
But I think it must be `type="application/x-silverlight-2"` and `data="data:application/x-silverlight-2,"`. And I don't know how to repair it.

Help, plz :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest one of two approaches.
1. Add the object tag into your HTML. This would always load the XAP on your page, which might not match your scenario, but it is easier.
2. Dig in to the Silverlight.js file and change it to the correct one. I'm using `<object id="slObject" data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width='960' height='351'>` with success.